# CloudHub and MMC in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Small query generally. If one got Mule EE with Cloudhub edition licence. MMC will come by default included in it or required to get the separate licencing for that.

If that is the case, what would be the deployment. Are we need to deploy the application separately  both in cloudhub and also in MMC.

Else MMC can be used only with standalone servers?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, MMC is only used with standalone servers. When using Cloudhub, you are able to manage applications via the [Cloudhub Console](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/CloudHub+Console+Overview)  (with no extra license) which allows you to perform tasks similar to those available in MMC. The features available are not identical to MMC's, they are intended only for Cloud applications.